# Authentication failed using Graph API

Tags: winforms, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to build a Windows form app for cloud migration and while authenticating OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API, i am getting this exception.

[image]

Please help or give any workaround

Comment: Microsoft Graph API expects "code" which you will get while the user logging into the application. If it is web application you can get it from querystring of the redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can execute a call against Microsoft Graph, you'll first need to [authenticate that user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) and retrieve an access token. Each time you make a call to Graph, you'll include this token in your HTTP request `Authorization` header.

In order operate against a user's data, you'll also need to request the proper [permission scopes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) during the authentication process. From what I understand of your scenario here , you'll need at least `Files.ReadWrite`.

If your application is build on .NET 4.5 or newer, you may also want to go with the [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph). This will simplify calling the API itself. It will *not* however handle the authorization process. For obtaining the token you can use [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client).

There is an excellent walkthrough for this as well: [Call the Microsoft Graph API from a Windows Desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-windesktop). While it isn't specific to Windows Forms, the concepts are pretty similar.